# Create SSH key within VSTS agent

Tags: azure, ssh-keys, azure-hdinsight

I am using VSTS to create Azure Linux VMs and was wondering if i can create SSH keys and store these in Keyvault within an hosted agent? As of now i have and agent phase that creates VMs, can i before these create and SSH key and store it in Keyvault.

have tried to find a method on creating a key within powershell, which seems not to be possible unless i install a separate tool, thus i was wondering if there is a component (task/phase) within VSTS that could create multiple keys?

Comment: Do you mean create multiple ssh keys by the agent machine? And what's the agent machine for you to queue build, hosted agent or private agent,and windows OS or linux OS?

Comment: no i want to create SSH keys for and HDinsight cluster, basicly i have created an action script (Bash) that configures ssh to require certificat and password when users login. when Cluster is create i loop through a JSON and add users including cert to nodes in cluster (this works fine). Now i want to create the ssh-key dynamicly (instead of using putty) and save this per user in keyvault, after which it will be pushed to HDinsight cluster.

Comment: I'm having an issue similar to this, but I am wanting to know where to put the SSH Private Key for Git ran by the VSTS Agent to mirror some repositories.